# can't import AssetsLibrary.h

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, ios6, xcode4.5

I want to use AssetsLibrary framework to use picture from users photo library. But i have a very strange issue. I see that everybody is importing this framework like this

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

But i can't and the compiler is showing errors. I even can't find it when adding frameworks in "Link Binaries With Libraries". As if this framework doesn't exist.

Maybe anybody has some similar issues and knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the framework is missing, I've looked for it in the framework dir and it wasn't there, so i chose to redownload new xcode. If anybody has some similar problems I recommend to first look if the framework is not missing in /System/Library/Frameworks/.

Comment: Running into this 4 years later... Thanks!